# merge strips timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging two dataframes:

```
df = pd.merge(source, extracted, left_on = 'SESSION_SCHED', right_on = 'COMPL_DATE')
```

Note that `SESSION_SCHED` is a date but does not have a timestamp. `COMPL_DATE` has a timestamp before the merge but not after.

Example:

```
>>> print(extracted['COMPL_DATE'])
0      2015-11-25 10:25:00
5      2016-09-30 13:31:00
10     2013-09-13 00:00:00
15     2014-12-18 17:00:00

>>> print(df['COMPL_DATE'])
0   2015-13-22
1   2013-01-30
2   2013-09-13
3   2011-10-18
4   2013-09-13
```

How can I merge the dataframes while keeping the timestamp in the `COMPL_DATE` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon review, the real reason the timestamp did not display after the merge is that the only rows that were selected in the merge had 00:00:00 for a timestamp. Hence, this time is assumed and not explicitly displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`extracted.assign(x=extracted['COMPL_DATE'].dt.normalize()` - will add a new column `x` with truncated time (i.e. `00:00:00`) - we can use this column for joining:

```
df = pd.merge(source, extracted.assign(x=extracted['COMPL_DATE'].dt.normalize()), 
              left_on = 'SESSION_SCHED', right_on = 'x')
```

Comment: Can you explain **why** this solves the issue instead of just posting some code? This will be far more helpful, especially for beginners, thanks.

Comment: @MaxU - thanks. One follow up, this doesn't seem to work if I am joining on multiple keys. That is, the two shown along with a few others. Any thoughts?

Comment: @kbball, could you provide small reproducible input data sets and desired data set? I guess it would make sense to open a new question...

Comment: Let me ask it this way - why did you use assign instead of adding a new column to the dataframe before the merge? Like this - df['x'] = ... And then joining on that column?

Comment: I used `assign()`, because you don't need that column after the join is done. I.e. we need it only for joining... So that column will be automatically purged from memory after the join is done

Comment: Thanks - see new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631983/merge-strips-timestamp-even-when-column-is-not-a-key.